# Button in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

I have a custom button and it's added to a static cell. Somehow whenever I tap the button, it doesn't react immediately like when the button is added to a plain normal view.

When tapped, it registers the tap right away but the background color has a slight delay before changing.

---

To change the color I have the following code in my subclass of `UIButton`:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    border.fillColor = .redColor()  // border is a CAShapeLayer
    print("began")                  // This prints right when the button is clicked
}
```

This button is added in a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and the button is reacting, except changing the color has a delay. How can I fix this?

**Answer (by Jelly):**
The answer of Jelly helped me a lot and made the button react a bit better. Knowing what the problem is also made it easier to research the problem and found out to make the button react just as it would in a normal view I have to disable both `delaysContentTouches` in the table view and it's subviews:

```
tableView.delaysContentTouches = false
tableView.subviews.forEach { ($0 as? UIScrollView)?.delaysContentTouches = false }
```

Comment: Why don't use `UIButton:addTarget` method instead of a tap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `delaysContentTouches = false` on your tableView.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know there was a default delay in a table view (I can accept it in 3 min).

Comment: Actually it is on `UIScrollView` from which `UITableView` inherits.

Comment: With your answer, it worked a bit better but still felt a bit off. So I've searched a bit more, which was easier knowing it was about `delaysContentTouches`. I've found out there's another `UIScrollView` in the subview of a table view and have to disable `delaysContentTouches` of that scroll view as well. I'll edit what I've done in my question.

Comment: I did not know that. Looks like I also learned something from your question.